# Why does my website not display when I switched my ingress to use a host path instead of defaultBackend?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

Good evening.  I successfully configured an ingress within my kubernetes cluster using `defaultBackend`; however, when I use `host` in my ingress rules, my ingress starts to fail. I am not sure why.

**Why, when I enter [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (or [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)) in my web browser (Chrome), can the site not be reached?**

I thought I was very thorough when reading the [Ingress docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/service-resources/ingress-v1/#IngressSpec)

- "www.example.com" is in my hosts file and pointed at 127.0.0.1
- I am using the Kubernetes distro that comes with Docker Desktop (v1.27.2).
- I am using NGINX ingress controller (installed via helm)
- My NGINX web server (example-gui service) is listening on port 8080
- The nginx.conf `http.server.server_name` is set to "www.example.com"
- All relevant pods, services, and ingresses show up when I run `kubectl get <ing|po|svc>`
- I am not using a proxy or VPN
- The website shows up if I visit localhost:30001

Here is my combined manifest for simple viewing:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: example-gui
    example: example-gui
    version: "0.1.0"
  name: example-gui
  namespace: exampleplus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example-gui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example-gui
        example: example-gui
        version: "2.0.4"
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: example-gui:0.1.0
          name: example-gui
          env:
            - name: DNS_SERVER
              value: kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always      
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    example: example-gui
  name: example-gui
  namespace: exampleplus
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: "example-gui-tcp"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30001
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    example: example-gui
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-example-gui
  namespace: exampleplus
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: "www.example.com" # port 80 is assumed
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: example-gui
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Comment: try 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Hi \`Robert S\` can you provide more details like where you have deployed this application I mean in cloud or locally on your system. If you have deployed locally can you try to check by disabling the internet. Also remove the nameserver config so that it will be resolved locally instead of going to a DNS server